# Change text when img link is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can you change the text color of the "a" that does not wrap the img link

```
<li>
    <a href="# WHEN I HOVER THIS IMG LINK I WANT A TAG BELOW TO CHANGE COLOR">
        <img alt="Franchise 16" src="#"></img>
    </a>
    <a href="# CHANGE THIS TEXT COLOR WHEN IMG ABOVE IS HOVERED">TEXT</a>
</li>
```

I have tried with css and I can't find a solution, do I need to use javascript?

Comment: You may find it helpful to view the [**w3 documentation on selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the immediate sibling selector

```
li a:first-child:hover + a {
    color: ....
}
```

Comment: Thx , was looking for simple css solution and this is it. li a:first-child:hover + a,li a:hover {
    color: green
}

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Can you please elaborate more about the immediate sibling selector?

Comment: It targets the first available adjacent sibling: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 0):

css should be like this

```
.testimg:hover .testtext
{
color:red;
}
```

and html should be like this

```
<li>
    <a class="testimg" href="# WHEN I HOVER THIS IMG LINK I WANT A TAG BELOW TO CHANGE COLOR">
        <img  alt="Franchise 16" src="#"></img>
    </a>
    <a class="testtext" href="# CHANGE THIS TEXT COLOR WHEN IMG ABOVE IS HOVERED">TEXT</a>
</li>
```

Comment: This selector means look for a descendant `.testext`, not a sibling.

Comment: U mean should be li.testtext or what ?

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
      $('#first-link').hover(function(){
        $('#second-link').css('color','red');
      });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<li>
    <a id="first-link" href="# WHEN I HOVER THIS IMG LINK I WANT A TAG BELOW TO CHANGE COLOR">
        <img alt="Franchise 16" src="#"></img>
    </a>
    <a id ="second-link" href="# CHANGE THIS TEXT COLOR WHEN IMG ABOVE IS HOVERED"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: A jquery solution for this kind of task should be avoided when a pure css approach is possible

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan "a pure css approach is possible" in which CSS version?

Comment: In css 2.1, with IE7 compatibility. Anyway OP tagged its question with css3 tag.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan The user tagged jquery and javascript in the question so I thought he looking to use them.

Comment: Yes, but my first comment is still valid

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I tend to agree with you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `~` operator, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/QAYLU/

#### HTML

```
<a href="#one" id="one">
    <img alt="Franchise 16" src="" width="100" height="100" />
</a>

<a href="#two" id="two">Two</a>
```

#### CSS

```
#one:hover ~ #two {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: If two has an _#id_; which by definition should be unique, there would be no point writing a selector like this.

Comment: Just added for reference. You can change from `#two` to `a`.

Comment: I would have used a _class_, because then the code is repeatable and the selector would still make sense.